# EOFError: EOF read where object expected

Tags: google-app-engine

Recently there have been strange errors on GAE, like this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
EOFError: EOF read where object expected
```

Not sure if the fault is in my app or on GAE. Anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 11):

Most likely a race condition when 3 or more Python processes read/write the same pyc file. Fixed in Python 3.3: http://bugs.python.org/issue13146

Answer (score 1):

If there is an instance currently running for your project, shut it down and startup a new instance. That seemed to fix it for me.

---

P.S. I had a weird error the other day that looked like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/upload.py", line 11, in <module>
    import traceback
SystemExit: -1
```

This error seems similar, in that it contains some of the same lines, but leads me to think that some instances were started incorrectly or something like that. Stopping the instance and starting up a new one fixed this error as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing exactly this error. Nothing to do with your app, I think, just some kind of transient problem with App Engine. I noticed a few instances of it around 4am GMT yesterday.

```
"/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
__import__(cumulative_path)
EOFError: EOF read where object expected
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was meanwhile using Django... Some Python2.7 .pyc installation packages were corrupt. rm -r -- **/*.pyc to delete all .pyc in the file system or more accurate:

> import sys
>   print '\n'.join(sys.path)

to check where is the installation folders and recursively delete all .pyc files and done it, Python starts working again

Comment: switch to python interpreter
execute the following commands
import sys
print '\n'.join(sys.path)

Change to the python path.
rm -r -- **/*.pyc

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same exact issue. It must be something wrong with App Engine. They've been having issues.

**Update:** Following rgutierrez1014's tip to shutdown any instances currently running fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error. Because the module that GAE was trying to load was in a bad state, this led to weird AttributeError, because the module partly loaded was in a bad state now. Restarting solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Issue 11776](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11776&thanks=11776&ts=1426191114) about this open on Google App Engine PIT, please feel free to Star in order to get notified of any updates about this issue.