# EOFError on stdlib import

Tags: python

We're running an HPC cluster that has many instances of Python running out of the same virtualenv directory.  We infrequently get Tracebacks with EOFErrors on import (usually on stdlib imports).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../env/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 67, in <module>
    import os
  File "../env/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 398, in <module>
    import UserDict
  File "../env/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 83, in <module>
    import _abcoll
  File "../env/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py", line 11, in <module>
    from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
  File "../env/lib/python2.7/abc.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _weakrefset import WeakSet
EOFError: EOF read where object expected
```

I've searched around online and mostly found discussions suggesting that [pyc file compilation](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/843933-race-condition-when-generating-pyc-files) was the issue, so I added a `compile.compileall('.')` to the start of our build pipeline and am now confident that every file has a corresponding .pyc file.  Any ideas on what else to check?

I can't provide a reproducible example because it only occurs infrequently under highly concurrent conditions.

Similar SO questions:

- Seen on GAE (doesn't apply because we're not using App Engine) - [EOFError: EOF read where object expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890754/eoferror-eof-read-where-object-expected)
- Tweepy - no answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28382529/tweepy-eoferror-eof-read-where-object-expected